# "Access denied: Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.list access to bucket" when trying to host a static website from a Google Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cname

I'm trying to follow the instructions on https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website to host a static website from a Google Bucket. I've created the CNAME alias, uploaded the content to a bucket named the same as the website (www.kurtpeek.com), and checked "Share publicly" for all items. However, when I browse to the website I see the following:

[image]

I've read on http://tekhoow.blogspot.be/2015/12/soving-accessdenied-on-google-cloud.html that this problem can be solved from the command line using [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil). However, I've done it before for a different website using the web-based console, I just don't remember how.

I suspect it should be somewhere in the "IAM" menu, but I can't seem to find the 'read public' options similar to the commands.

[image]

Can anyone point out the 'missing ingredient' to make the website work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally did use the command-line solution:

```
~$ gsutil web set -m index.html gs://www.kurtpeek.com
Setting website configuration on gs://www.kurtpeek.com/...
```

and now the website works as expected.